# AlertDialog Title textsize , Title textColor change on android

Tags: android

I want to show the stacktrace in a dialog.
Here is the dialog:

```
  AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle(title)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setMessage("Occur exception, please click me")
                    .show();
            TextView textView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            textView.setTextSize(30);
```

It's working, but I want to change the title textsize and title textColor.
I tried:

```
TextView titleView = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
titleView.setTextSize(40);
```

It did not work. Perhaps, it is impossible to change title color and text size?

Comment: You need to create a custom dialog. Have you seen this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341560/how-to-create-a-custom-dialog-box-in-android) before?

Comment: @McAwesomville   thanks so much! :)

Comment: No worries. Gonna tag this as a duplicate then. Happy coding. Cheers! :)

Comment: perhaps, I want not xml, my dialog titleText, get  another method . is possible?

Comment: ah,, and I alertdialog in thread